# How to query db to get all objects that match a list of parameters, instead of just the last item in the list

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a `Job` object and each one has a `zip_code` field. I am trying to loop through a list of zip codes and get all matching `Job` objects. But with my current query, instead of appending the additional `Job` objects to `jobs_matching_query`, `jobs_matching_query` is reset every time, leading to only the `Job` objects with the last zip code in the list (10564 in the bottom example) being returned. How can I query my db so that all `Job` objects with zip codes in `zip_codes_within_15_mile_radius` are returned?

my code:

```
zip_codes_within_15_mile_radius = ['10535', '10579', '10564']
for zip_code in zip_codes_within_15_mile_radius:
    jobs_matching_query = Job.objects.filter(zip_code__iexact = zip_code) #this query only returns jobs that have '10564' as their zip code
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of loop you probably can use [`__in`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#in) lookup:

```
jobs_matching_query = Job.objects.filter(zip_code__in = zip_codes_within_15_mile_radius)
```

Comment: I figured it was a simple solution, thanks! will accept the answer when it allows me too